# Wait for another method to execute..then continue

Tags: java, android

Actually a basic Java question which I did not come along when I was learning this programming language.

For best understanding my question I will provide a simple sample:

```
block of code {

-new AsynTask..

-some code which I want to execute after AsyncTask finishes executing..

}
```

I know I can put the second line of code in postExcecute in AsyncTask object. But is it possible for program flow to continue after AsyncTask is finished executing?

Comment: not without blocking the UI. you need to use `onPostExecute`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to do this.  This totally destroys the purpose of using an AsyncTask-  it will halt the original thread until the task is done, preventing it from doing other things.  If you wanted to do that, you'd be better off without the task.  Instead, you should put the code you want to execute after the task is done in the onPostExecute method of the AsyncTask.

Comment: i am just curious, why do you want to use aynctask then ?

Comment: Purpose of AsyncTask is to connect to a webserver and reterive some data. After data is reterived I want to save it to a local database (second method). But I will do that in postExecute now.